# Swift Cannot convert return expression of type "CameraScreen" to return type 'UIView?'

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I am trying to make a swift camera screen so that I can use it in react native. I keep running into this error `Cannot convert return expression of type "CameraScreen" to return type 'UIView?'`

I tried changing `UIViewController` to `UIView` and had more errors. I am extremely new to swift. So if anyone can help me resolve my error in trying to make a custom camera screen I will be extremely grateful.

**This is my code:**

```
//  CameraScreen.swift

import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


//@objc(CameraScreen)
class CameraScreen : UIViewController {

  //capture session
  var session: AVCaptureSession?
  //photo output
  let output = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
  //video preview
  let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()
  // Shutter button
  private let shutterButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 100
    button.layer.borderWidth = 10
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    return button
  }()
  
//  override func viewDidLoad(){
//    super.viewDidLoad()
//    view.backgroundColor = .black
//    checkCameraPermissons()
//  }
  

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
      checkCameraPermissons()

    }
  
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    checkCameraPermissons()
    }
  
  private func checkCameraPermissons(){
    switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video){
      case .notDetermined:
        // Request
      AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { [weak self] granted in
        guard granted else{
          return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self?.setUpCamera()
        }
      }
    case .restricted:
      break
    case .denied:
      break
    case .authorized:
      setUpCamera()
      
    @unknown default:
      break
      }
  }
  
  private func setUpCamera(){
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video){
      do{
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device:device)
        if session .canAddInput(input){
          session.addInput(input)
        }
        if session.canAddOutput(output){
          session.addOutput(output)
        }
        
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        previewLayer.session = session
        
        session.startRunning()
        self.session = session
      }
      catch{
        print(error)
      }
    }
  }
  
}

@objc (RCTCameraScreenManager)
class RCTCameraScreenManager: RCTViewManager {
 
  override static func requiresMainQueueSetup() -> Bool {
    return true
  }
 
  override func view() -> UIView! {
    return CameraScreen(coder: <#NSCoder#>) // this is the line with the error
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you need to return a `UIView`, sub-classing `UIViewController` isn't going to work.  As for other errors, I'm guessing you want the `CameraScreen` constructor that takes a `frame` parameter rather than `coder`.  (I assume your "more errors" is because you're not actually supplying a `<#NSCoder#>` object.)

Comment: @PhillipMills Thank you so much for your response. Is there any way I can use a `UIViewController` for my app and change that override function on the last part to accept using a `UIViewController`? I think my way of overriding is not correct.

Comment: It depends on what `RCTViewManager` requires and how it's used.  Since its name suggests that it manages *views* then changing to a controller doesn't sound right.  Maybe you need a `CameraView` and a `CameraViewController` but I can't see your app's structure to say for sure.

Comment: @PhillipMills Okay I will use UIVIew since` RCTViewManager` requires a view. Is there any way I can make a working camera preview using `UIView`?